# Had to hard-code $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = true in index.php for Phorge (Phabricator)

Tags: phabricator, phorge

I was following a guide to enable SSL with nginx on my Phorge machine, and for some reason, all assets like CSS and JS still went to http. When adding return 301 in nginx config, the site didn't load because of faulty redirect. Instead I could hard-code

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = true
```

in index.php, which made all assets load via https.

This is by design or? What's the proper configuration here?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right fcgi parameters in nginx? Something like "fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;" should be there to tell php you're 
                using https

Comment: Thanks for this question. If you can, please share your nginx configuration.

Comment: Note that this question is probably not related to programming. Maybe somebody would suggest to migrate on Server Fault to continue this discussion there